# MATLAB read binary file

Tags: matlab

I am trying to read a binary file generated by LABVIEW (1000 sample sine wave, freq 0.01 and amplitude of 6000) with MATLAB

I am using this simple code:

```
fid = fopen('BinaryFile.bin');
m5 = fread(fid);
fclose(fid);
```

MATLAB shows me a 8000x1 vector!! I don't understand why, any help would be appreciated.

I cannot find any way to attach the binary file!!

Comment: What is the size of the file in Kb? what was the datatype in LabVIEW before saving it (double)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to define the `'precision'` argument in `fread`?

```
m5 = fread( fid, [], 'double' );
```

Comment: Thanks Shai for the answer. My new problem is I don